# Bootstrap - dynamic size of items

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm building a screen using Bootstrap and I don't know the correct way to reach the expected result.

Basically, what I need is have resizable items in the screen, when it has only one item, this item fills the entire space and when there are multiple items, resize them equally, like the images below.

[image: Multiple items]

[image: Single item]

The HTML that I have so far:

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid nopadding">
    <header class="container-fluid header">
      <span>MINI RADICAL KART</span>
      <section class="floating-buttons-box">
        <a class="btn-floating green-gradient play"><img src="assets/imgs/play_button.png" width="12"/></a>
        <a class="btn-floating black-gradient add"><img src="assets/imgs/plus_button.png" width="20"/></a>
      </section>
    </header>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="clock" class="col-md-5 timer">
        <h2>Kart 01</h2>
        <h1 class="time">04:32</h1>
        <div class="buttons">
          <img src="assets/imgs/pause_button.png" class="stop-button"/>
          <img src="assets/imgs/single_play_button.png" class="play-button"/>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Countdown JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var fiveSeconds = new Date().getTime() + 5000;
    $('#clock').countdown(fiveSeconds, {elapse: true})
      .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
        $(".time").text(event.strftime('%M:%S'));
        if (event.elapsed) {
          $(".time").removeClass("green");
          $(".time").addClass("red");
        } else {
          $(".time").removeClass("red");
          $(".time").addClass("green");
        }
      });

    $('.stop-button').click(function() {
      $('div#clock').countdown('pause');
    });

    $('.play-button').click(function() {
      $('div#clock').countdown('resume');    
    });
  </script>

</body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, You use flex?

Comment: No, what is it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dlishtvan/ad10cfeh/1/ - u need something like this?

Comment: @jackcar Can you add it in jsfidddle? with useful resources

Comment: He uses col classes in his code. Bootstrap 4 grids uses flex by default.

Comment: @DmytroLishtvan thank you very much, that was exactly what I needed.

Comment: ok, I add answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here is what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/dlishtvan/ad10cfeh/1) - u must use `display: flex;`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col mx-4 bg-danger">
      thing
    </div>
    <div class="col mx-4 bg-success">
      thing
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col mx-4 bg-secondary">
      thing
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, every `col` has the same classes, but on the second row I only have one `col`, that streches automatically to full size.

You can play around with this, and create what you need!